# Magento "setup:upgrade" corrupts the installation

Tags: magento2

I updated my Magento 2.4.1 installation to 2.4.2 a while ago.

Since then it works as expected. No problems.

But now I discovered that wenn I call magento setup:upgrade the update starts and after all finishes, I can't see the options in my configurable products (sizes, colors,...). They are just gone. I have no clue why.

Before the upgrade

[image: Image.jpeg]

After the upgrade

[image: Image.jpeg]

The configuration options are missing after the upgrade and the console shows me an error which was not present before.

[image: Image.jpeg]

`…/static/version1623092606/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/configurableVariationQty.js`

And I can't find a file called `configurableVariationQty.js` anywhere on my server. Where does it come from? Should it have been installed with the upgrade?

Does anybody have a clue what’s going on here? How can I gather more information?

Comment: Are you actually redeploying static view files after running a setup:upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked it down finally.

This issue helped me find the solution:
https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3276

The patch, referenced in the last post (https://github.com/magento/inventory/commit/337f8b7d56d81c217d5bf2bac180b315fd6120d0#diff-669c3cc08f646d82fcfa47b2385c3301fb1ee58c863ab0c91812e9e0482d8569) helped me to solve my problem.

`InventoryCatalogFrontendUi/Model/GetProductQtyLeft.php` already looked like the patched version in my installation.

But I had to patch `InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-variation-qty.js` in my installation.

After adding the `&& response.qty > 0` all worked well again.

This error was gone
[image]
and the configurable options showed up again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running production mode (see `bin/magento deploy:mode:show`), you need to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` after setup:upgrade, as well.
It might also be needed to reindex with `bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

Comment: I'll run both commands now and get back to you later, after the reindex finishes.

Comment: Alright, don't forget to flush the cache, I totally forgot.

Comment: Sorry, I was "out of order" ###

It did not help. The setup seems to be broken somehow. It works without errors on the frontend and is fully functional, but as soon as I call setup:upgrade it is broken afterwards.

Next thing I tried is to setup a new instance from scratch with 2.4.2-p1 and bring over all data from production. But I couldn't figure out how to make it work (configurable products made some problems).